# Select Similar Titles From a Table With a Single Query

Tags: mysql

I would like to query a single table and select any entries which have similar titles. A similar title is a title with exactly the same string (case insensitive) but with "(fresh)" appended. The result should return the `id` and `title` of any matches.

For example if this was my table:

```
ID    TITLE
1     Bacon
2     Eggs
3     Eggs (fresh)
4     ketchup
5     Ketchup (Fresh)
```

Then I'd like to extract:

```
array(
    array(
        id => 2
        title => Eggs
    ),
    array(
        id => 3
        title => Eggs (fresh)
    )
),
array(
    array(
        id => 4
        title => ketchup
    ),
    array(
        id => 5
        title => Ketchup (Fresh)
    )
)
```

Currently I'm using two separate queries. First I select all titles and then I do a loop to find which entries have those titles with "(fresh)" appended. I'm sure there must be a more efficient way to extract these matching titles in a single query but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: What are the queries you're using now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select src.id ID_wo_fresh, tgt.id ID_w_fresh, src.title
from tbl src
inner join tbl tgt on src.title= replace(replace(tgt.title,' (fresh)',''),' (Fresh)','')
and src.id <> tgt.id
```

This will return the ID of product without 'fresh' or 'Fresh' in the name, the ID with 'fresh' or 'Fresh' in the name and the name itself. Note that this will exclude rows which don't find a match i.e. only have the name with or without suffix, but not both. To show for all rows, use `left join` instead.

Comment: That's great, inner joining on the same table is what I was looking for.